# How to compare two directory and get the differences list on AIX

Tags: unix

I want to compare two dirs, and just need to compare the file size. The result would be a diffs list, not contains the details. I searched web, and find that there's parameter -q of the command diff, but which seems not available in my AIX distro. Is there any other way to take on this?

Comment: `diff -q` will give you the **list** of changed files, while you say you want to compare the difference in file **sizes**.

Answer (score 1):

To diff the file sizes you can do:

```
ls -ltr dir1 > dir1_files
ls -ltr dir2 > dir2_files
diff dir1_files dir2_files
```